# Does the mxnet symbol API support conditional control flow?

Tags: mxnet

I want to add some conditional control in my symbol, it seems that if-else is evaluated in symbol construction time. But I want it to evaluated in symbol run time.

```
a = mx.symbol.Variable(name='a')
b = mx.symbol.Variable(name='b')

if a>b:
    c = a-b
else:
    c = a+b
```

TensorFlow provides the tf.cond() operator to deal with it, is there a counterpart in mxnet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [mx.symbol.where](http://mxnet.io/api/python/symbol.html#mxnet.symbol.where).

You can compute `a_minus_b` and `a_plus_b` and return an array where each element is either from `a_minus_b` or `a_plus_b` depending on the corresponding value in another `condition` array. Here is an example:

```
a = mx.symbol.Variable(name='a')
b = mx.symbol.Variable(name='b')

a_minus_b = a - b
a_plus_b  = a + b

# gt = a > b
gt = a.__gt__(b) 

result = mx.sym.where(condition=gt, x=a_minus_b, y=a_plus_b)

ex = result.bind(ctx=mx.cpu(), args={'a':mx.nd.array([1,2,3]), 'b':mx.nd.array([3,2,1])})
r = ex.forward()

print(r[0].asnumpy()) #result should be [1+3, 2+2, 3-1]
```